# In Power Automate, is there a way to filter on a Custom Field using DevOp's Send HTTP Request?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, power-automate

I'm trying to use Power Automate to return a custom work item in Azure DevOps using the "workitemsearch" API (via the "Send HTTP Request" action).  Part of this will require me to filter based on the value of a Custom Field, however, I have not been able to get it to work.  Here is a copy of my HTTP Request Body:

```
{
  "searchText": "ValueToSearch",
  "$skip": 0,
  "$top": 1,
  "filters": {
    "System.TeamProject": ["MyProject"],
    "System.AreaPath": ["MyAreaPath"],
    "System.WorkItemType": ["MyCustomWorkItem"],
    "Custom.RequestNumber": ["ValueToSearch"]
  },
  "$orderBy": [
    {
      "field": "system.id",
      "sortOrder": "ASC"
    }
  ],
  "includeFacets": true
}
```

I have been able to get it to work by removing the *Custom.RequestNumber": ["ValueToSearch"]* but am hesitant to use that in case my ValueToSearch is found in other places like the comments of other work items.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `WorkItemSearchResponse`, we can see the `facets` (A dictionary storing an array of `Filter` object against each facet) only supports the following fields:

```
    "System.TeamProject"
    "System.WorkItemType"
    "System.State":
    "System.AssignedTo"
```

If you want to filter `RequestNumber`, you can just set it in the `searchText` as the following syntax:

`"searchText": "RequestNumber:ValueToSearch"`

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!